# w3wp using between 700mb-1.2gb of memory not under load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, redgate

I have an MVC3 app using EF/Autofac and memcached (3 front end servers). When starting up the app it will quickly jump up to 300mb with one user. On our production site (where the traffic is low (< 10 users at any one time)) it can easily reach over 1.2gb of memory. This seems like a very large number to me.

I have tried Redgate Memory Profiler but I just can't seem to find anything that looks out of the ordinary.

The only thing I can think of is perhaps the following code is causing some kind of memory leakage what do you think?

```
private Dictionary<string, object> cacheDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private IMemcachedClient _client;

    public MemcachedManager(IMemcachedClient client)
    {
        this._client = client;
    }

    #region ICacheManager Members

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        object data;
        if (!cacheDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out data))
        {
            byte[] byteData = _client.Get<byte[]>(key);
            data = CommonHelper.Deserialize<T>(byteData);
            cacheDictionary.Add(key, data);
        }
        return (T)data;
    }

    public void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
    {
        if (!cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key)) //if memcache turned off this should still work
            cacheDictionary.Add(key, data);

        data = CommonHelper.Serialize(data);
        bool setCache = _client.Store(StoreMode.Set, key, data, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheTime));

        if (!setCache)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("Failed to set the cache item, key {0}", key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't clear the cacheDictionary how is the memory supposed to be released? Is IIS configured to recycle app processes?

Comment: The cache dictionary is supposed to be released after the request is complete. If this is not the case how do I release this dictionary?

Comment: If that is the case then maybe your servers have a lot of memory and the app is experiencing no real memory pressure so the GC is taking its time to clean up. Still you should look more into the lifetime of your MemcachedManager object.

Comment: My memcached manager is registered with autofac like so:builder.RegisterType<MemcachedManager>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("cache_static_mem").InstancePerHttpRequest();

Comment: Is your machine running low on memory?

Comment: No my machine has plenty of memory to spare.